# Estimating AR(1) coefficient using metropolis-Hastings algorithm (MCMC) in R

Tags: r, mcmc

I am trying to write a program to estimate AR(1) coefficients using metropolis-hastings algorithm. My R code is as following,

```
set.seed(101)

#loglikelihood
logl <- function(b,data) {
  ly = length(data)
  -sum(dnorm(data[-1],b[1]+b[2]*data[1:(ly-1)],(b[3])^2,log=TRUE))
}


#proposal function
proposalfunction <- function(param,s){
  return(rnorm(3,mean = param, sd= s))
}

#MH sampler
MCMC <- function(startvalue, iterations,data,s){
  i=1
  chain = array(dim = c(iterations+1,3))
  chain[i,] = startvalue
  while (i <= iterations){
    proposal = proposalfunction(chain[i,],s)
    probab = exp(logl(proposal,data = data) - logl(chain[i,],data = data))
    if(!is.na(probab)){
      if (runif(1) <= min(1,probab)){
        chain[i+1,] = proposal
      }else{
        chain[i+1,] = chain[i,]
      }
      i=i+1
    }else{
      cat('\r !')
    }
  }
  acceptance = round((1-mean(duplicated(chain)))*100,1)
  print(acceptance)
  return(chain)
}

#example
#generating data
data <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.7), n = 2000,sd = sqrt(1))

r=MCMC(c(0,.7,1),50000,data,s=.00085)
```

In the example, I must get zero for the mean and 0.7 for the coefficient and 1 for error variance. but everytime I run this code I get completely different values. I tried to adjust proposal scale but still I get the results that are far from the true values. Figure below shows the results.

[image]

Comment: What are "funny" results?  Can you please explain the results and what you think the desired results should be.

Comment: yes. I must get zero for the mean and 0.7 for the coefficient and 1 for error variance. but everytime I get completely different values

Comment: Wouldn't you expect different results because of the `proposalfunction` using `rnorm`?

Comment: I think it is not a matter of proposal. Can you explain that more? I also added a figure to clarify the problem.

Comment: The `rnorm()` function produces random sample of a normal distribution, so you'll get different numbers each time.  You would expect your results to be different

Comment: there's clearly something wrong with the way you're estimating the variance parameter (the other parameters aren't mixing very well, but the variance parameter seems to be continually increasing).  You do have a mistake in your log-likelihood (`dnorm` takes the sd, not the variance, as its third argument) but I don't think that would cause these symptoms ...

Answer (score 2):

You've flipped the sign in your log-likelihood function.  This is an easy mistake to make because maximum likelihood estimation usually proceeds by *minimizing the negative log-likelihood*, but the requirement in MCMC is to be working with the likelihood itself (not its inverse).

Also:

- `dnorm()` takes the standard deviation as its third argument, not the variance. You can simplify your code slightly by using `head(data,-1)` to get all but the last element in a vector.  So your log-likelihood would be:

```
sum(dnorm(data[-1],b[1]+b[2]*head(data,-1),b[3],log=TRUE))
```

- you're probably hurting yourself by fixing the candidate distribution to be independent Normal with equal SDs for all variables; allowing them to differ (although the posterior SDs are not as different as I thought they might be - about {0.02,0.016,0.0077} - so this might not be such a big problem.